# Query that allows double Search

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

This is the current table i Have.

```
WeldingProcedure  
ID        TYPE     Metal1        Metal2      ThicknessMin       ThicknessMax
50-1      SMAW       1             2              1                  2
50-2      SAW        2             2              3                  5
51-3      FCAW       3             2              2                  6
52-1      SMAW       1             2             0.5                 2
```

The current query that i have is

```
SELECT *
FROM WeldingProcedure as WPS
WHERE WPS.[Metal#(P-No)]=Forms!MatchSearch_form!metal1  
And WPS.[Metal#2(P-No)]=Forms!MatchSearch_form!metal2   
And WPS.ThicknessMin<=Forms!MatchSearch_form!thickness
And WPS.ThicknessMax>=Forms!MatchSearch_form!thickness
And WPS.[Welding _Type]=Forms!MatchSearch_form!weldingtype
```

So when i search with the criteria of:

```
Type = SMAW  
Metal1 = 1
Metal2 = 2
Thickness = 1.5
```

I get the result of

```
ID        TYPE     Metal1        Metal2      ThicknessMin      ThicknessMax
50-1      SMAW       1             2              1                  2
52-1      SMAW       1             2             0.5                 2
```

I want the user to also be able to key in

```
Type = SMAW  
Metal1 = 2
Metal2 = 1
Thickness = 1.5
```

And get the same result. What can i do to change the query to make that happen? It would cog up the tables if i key in the values twice.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand... you want your user to be able to type in information which does not match any of the rows in your table and return the a result based on that? Or are you looking to have multiple Metal1 and Metal2 values per ID?

Comment: Yeah to @Wolves point, Metal2 = 1 would return nothing ? If however you want metal 1 and metal 2 to be treated as one that is a different story

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    WeldingProcedure as WPS
WHERE   ((WPS.[Metal#(P-No)] = Forms!MatchSearch_form!metal1 AND WPS.[Metal#2(P-No)] = Forms!MatchSearch_form!metal2) OR (WPS.[Metal#(P-No)] = Forms!MatchSearch_form!metal2 AND WPS.[Metal#2(P-No)] = Forms!MatchSearch_form!metal1))
        AND WPS.ThicknessMin<=Forms!MatchSearch_form!thickness
        AND WPS.ThicknessMax>=Forms!MatchSearch_form!thickness
        AND WPS.[Welding _Type]=Forms!MatchSearch_form!weldingtype
```

Comment: I am having syntax errors on
 SELECT  WPS.[Metal#(P-No)], WPS.[Metal#2(P-No)]
        INTERSECT
        (
        SELECT  Forms!MatchSearch_form!metal1, Forms!MatchSearch_form!metal2
        UNION
        SELECT  Forms!MatchSearch_form!metal2, Forms!MatchSearch_form!metal1
        )

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using access 2007

Comment: @raymondSee: yeah I figured out from your previous posts. See the update.

Comment: Jokes on me, I didnt realize i could just do a bracket and add a OR to it... THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the user to input 2 values and return records that have Metal1 and Metal2 equal to those two values, but the user can enter the values in either order (i.e. enter Metal1 then Metal2 or enter Metal2 then Metal1).

If that is the case, then this is the query you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM WeldingProcedure as WPS
WHERE 
(
    (WPS.[Metal#(P-No)]=Forms!MatchSearch_form!metal1 And WPS.[Metal#2(P-No)]=Forms!MatchSearch_form!metal2)
    OR
    (WPS.[Metal#(P-No)]=Forms!MatchSearch_form!metal2 And WPS.[Metal#2(P-No)]=Forms!MatchSearch_form!metal1)
)
And WPS.ThicknessMin<=Forms!MatchSearch_form!thickness
And WPS.ThicknessMax>=Forms!MatchSearch_form!thickness
And WPS.[Welding _Type]=Forms!MatchSearch_form!weldingtype
```

Comment: Jokes on me, I didnt realize i could just do a bracket and add a OR to it...Thanks!!!

Comment: @raymondSee No, the joke's on me. I answered the question, but you didn't upvote it and chose to accept another answer which originally wasn't as simple or efficient and didn't actually work for you until it was edited to be a copy of my answer. So, sour grapes? Yes. :)  But it's warm and sunny outside, so my day is going pretty good anyway.

Comment: LOL for some reason, it didnt get upvoted and answered. So sorry about that.